# Update between tables

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have two tables (ORACLE11) :

```
TABLE1: (ID_T1 is TABLE1 primary key)
| ID_T1 | NAME  | DATEBEGIN  | DATEEND    |
| 10    | test  | 01/01/2017 | 01/06/2017 |
| 11    | test  | 01/01/2017 | null       |
| 12    | test1 | 01/01/2017 | 01/06/2017 |
| 13    | test1 | 01/01/2017 | null       |
```

```
TABLE2: (ID_T2 is TABLE2 primary key and ID_T1 is TABLE2 foreign key on TABLE1)
| ID_T2 | ID_T1 |
| 1     | 10    |
| 2     | 11    |
| 3     | 11    |
| 4     | 12    |
| 5     | 13    |
```

I need to delete all rows from TABLE1 where TABLE1.DATEEND = 'null'

But first I must update TABLE2 to modify TABLE2.ID_T1 to the remaining record in TABLE1 for the same NAME :

```
TABLE2:
| ID_T2 | ID_T1 |
| 1     | 10    |
| 2     | 10    |
| 3     | 10    |
| 4     | 12    |
| 5     | 12    |
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE TABLE2 
SET TABLE2.ID_T1 = (
    SELECT TABLE1.ID_T1 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE TABLE1.DATEBEGIN = '01/01/2017' 
    AND TABLE1.DATEEND IS NOT NULL
    )
WHERE TABLE2.ID_T1 = (
    SELECT TABLE1.ID_T1 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE TABLE1.DATEBEGIN = '01/01/2017' 
    AND TABLE1.DATEEND IS NULL
    );
```

But I don't know how to join on TABLE1.NAME and do it for all rows of TABLE2. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: so what is the rule for reassigning `TABLE2.ID_T1`? Is it highest value of  `TABLE1.ID_T1` which is lower than current value of `TABLE2.ID_T1` where `TABLE1.DATEEND` is not null?

Comment: Or are you guaranteeing that `TABLE1` will always only have one record per `NAME` where `DATEEND` is not null?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that there is only one record per NAME where DATEEND is not null

Comment: Oracle is (in many cases) a multi-user environment. You will likely have to lock both tables for the duration of your operations. Imagine: You update an ID in table 2, the someone else adds a new row for a name in table 1 and changed the date for that name for the most recent row to NULL. Then you delete all the rows in table 1 with NULL date - including a row that YOU didn't think would be deleted. Now you lost the connection between the tables. So you must make sure that can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

First create a temp table to find out which id is to be retained for which name. In the case od multiple possible values, I have selected one by ascending order or id_t1.

```
create table table_2_update as 
select id_t1, name from (select id_t1, name row_number() over(partition by 
name order by id_t1) from table1 where name is not null) where rn=1;
```

Create next table to know which id of table2 connects to which name of table1.

```
create table which_to_what as 
select t2.id_t2, t2.id_t1, t1.name from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on 
t1.id_t1 = t2.id_t2 group by t2.id_t2, t2.id_t1, t1.name;
```

Since this newly created table now contains id and name of table1, and id of table2, merge into it to retain one to one case of id and name of table1.

```
merge into which_to_what a
using table_2_update b
on (a.name=b.name)
when matched then update set 
a.id_t1=b.id_t1;
```

Now finally we have a table which contains the final correct values, you can either rename this tale to table2 or merge original table2 on the basis of id of new table and original table2.

```
merge into table2 a
using which_to_what a
on (a.id_t2=b.id_t2)
when matched then update set
a.id_t1=b.id_t1;
```

Finally delete null values from table1.

```
delete from table1 where dateend is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining `table1` to itself, joining on the `name` column. Use the first table (a) to link to `table2.id_t1` and the second table (b) to get the `t1_id` where `dateend` is not null.

```
UPDATE table2
SET table2.id_t1 = (
    select b.id_t1
    from   table1 a, table1 b
    where  a.name = b.name
    and    b.dateend is not null
    and    a.id_t1 = table2.id_t1
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    select b.id_t1
    from   table1 a, table1 b
    where  a.name = b.name
    and    b.dateend is not null
    and    a.id_t1 = table2.id_t1
);
```

This assumes that there will only be one `table1` record where `dateend` is not null.